# Scrolling text in a dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, scroll, marquee

I' m experiencing a little problem reguarding the marquee tag.

I have a select dropdown menu, which has some option. Some of those option contain text longer then the width of the select tag.
I just want to make those text scroll from right to left. I tryied out the marquee but it haven' worked.
Any idea on how to show the hidden overflow text? It's not necessary that the texts moves, I would like to add the chance to view the cut text. Resizing is not allowed in this case(most of the option are made of just one or two words, the others are quite longer)

Thank you all for your attention.

Filippo

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this with plain HTML. `marquee` can not be inserted inside a `select`. I would try a plugin for customizing selects: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Thank you. what about onmouseover? Can I open a label whith the entire text?

Comment: You could try setting `position: relative` to your options and on hover give them a negative `margin-left`, but I don't think it will work. For further questions, I suggest you setting up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)